# Can’t stream BBCIplayer content

Tags: firefox, streaming

Just downloaded Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.
Complete novice.

Play DRM-controlled content is ticked.
Autoplay settings are set to “allow audio and video”
Privacy Badger set to Disable Privacy Badger for this site

Still can’t stream anything on BBC IPLAYER and BritBox etc.

What else can I do please.

Comment: BBC Iplayer and Britbox content may be restricted in your area. You may need to use a VPN to disguise your true location.

Comment: I’m in the uk so no issues with needing a vpn. The error message is not the same as the overseas “this content is not available in your area”. It says “This content doesn’t seem to be working. Please try again later.”  It never works.

Comment: Have you looked at this advice from the BBC? https://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/help/questions/playback-issues/outside-uk-message

Comment: It’s something to do with the Firefox settings. I’ve set the obvious ones but still no joy.  There is something that I’m missing. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but I live in France so no chance of me checking this out for myself :( Have you tried it with Chromium or a different browser?

Answer (score 0):

Installing libavcodec-extra helped me with this issue:

```
sudo apt install libavcodec-extra
```

Picked from https://askubuntu.com/a/1295118/363976.