# Firefox not playing videos on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: firefox, video

My newly deployed `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS` has already installed `Firefox 80`, but most videos in the web are not playable. One codec complains "No video formats available", while the other, for example, youtube, says that my browser can't play **HTML5** videos.

*What I've tried?*

- Reinstall the browser
- Install the `flash` plugin(deprecated technology, I know)
- Install the `widevine` extension. [Followed instruction](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1207502)

These solutions didn't help me a lot: the top result reached is watching videos on the sites supporting `flash` content.

So, what should I do? Please, instruct me!

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Bro, a solution for your problem takes no more than one line :)

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

That's all! After restarting your firefox browser the changes are applied and the browser plays any video content you wish.

**P.S.** I lost 2 annoying days searching the web for solution, trying different approaches, rolling back changes, reinstalling browser and so on, and try to imagine my face when this single line appeared the solution.

Comment: works like a charm, thanx !

Comment: Absolutely does not work.  I get some permissions boilerplate that needs to be OK'ed, but one cannot Okay it.  The open terminal just sits there uselessly.

Comment: Soooo sorry, this answer does work.  I FORGOT you can get to OK by using TAB.  My bad.  I'll promote answer once the system unlocks.  It works great and many thanks.

Comment: @KCinAZ Oh, I guess I know what are you talking about. While troubleshooting one problem(concerned with libreoffice) I also faced that strange menu which asked me to agree, but I didn't know how to do it. I was a newbie in using terminal in that moment, so I just pressed random buttons until it worked.

Comment: Works for me too. TY @scraaappy!

Comment: Saved my day :)

Comment: I had ffmpeg already installed. All I had to do was update the system and there was an update for ffmpeg and firefox.

Comment: This will install more packages than necessary, all you need is to install libavcodec-extra directly instead.

Comment: Confirmed that this solution works immediately after applying it. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 21.10. I already had ffmpeg and libavcodec-extra installed before I came here.

Answer (score 13):

You may also try

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu-restricted-extras) for what it installs.

Comment: Exactly the same problem as above.  You cannot OK the dialog.

Comment: @KCinAZ Navigating within a shell dialogue box seems like a separate problem. Hopefully you figured it out by now using your keyboard keys (tab, shift+tab, arrows, space, enter, etc).

Comment: Other pages suggested this too. It wanted 150MB disk space which I couldn't get back, or repeat. I recommend @mathway's ffmpeg and DRM method over this.

Comment: I prefer to install `sudo apt install ffmpeg`. It's a more controlled and open-sourcy way.

Comment: As with ffmpeg and libavcodec-extra, this also didn't work for me (Ubuntu 21.10).

Answer (score 12):

Just Open Terminal and paste:

```
sudo apt install libavcodec-extra -y
```

Restart Firefox and video playback will be working.

Comment: This works fine for me !!  I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Comment: This is the correct answer.